# ¿Cómo pasar valores de una columna a dos columnas diferentes en la misma tabla MySql sin que los valores no se repitan?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla en la cual guardo fotos de tamaño grande (big) y mediano (medium):

```
|----------------|-------------------|
|   articulo_id  |       foto        |
|----------------|-------------------|
|       1        |  fot1-medium.jpg  |
|       1        |   fot1-big.jpg    |
|       1        |  fot2-medium.jpg  |
|       1        |   fot2-big.jpg    |
|       3        |  foto-medium.jpg  |
|       4        |   foto-big.jpg    |
|       3        |   foto-big.jpg    |
|      ...       |         ...       |
```

A la hora de enseñar photos en la página, necesito photo grande y pequeña en el mismo bucle, por lo que quiero obtener de la tabla algo como esto:

```
|----------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|   articulo_id  |   foto_medium     |    foto_big       |
|----------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|       1        |  fot2-medium.jpg  |   fot2-big.jpg    |
|       1        |  fot1-medium.jpg  |   fot1-big.jpg    |
```

Actualmente tengo esta query:

```
SELECT a.foto as medium, b.foto as big
    FROM photos a
        JOIN photos b ON a.articulo_id = b.articulo_id
    WHERE 1
    AND a.foto LIKE '%medium.jpg'
    AND b.foto LIKE '%big.jpg'
    AND a.service_id = 1;
```

Que me devuelve filas duplicadas asi:

```
|----------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|   articulo_id  |   foto_medium     |    foto_big       |
|----------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|       1        |  fot2-medium.jpg  |   fot2-big.jpg    |
|       1        |  fot2-medium.jpg  |  fot2-medium.jpg  |
|       1        |  fot1-medium.jpg  |   fot1-big.jpg    |
|       1        |  fot1-medium.jpg  |  fot1-medium.jpg  |
```

¿Cómo pasar valores de una columna a dos columnas diferentes en la misma tabla MySql sin que los valores no se repitan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba utilizando subconsultas. Algo asi debería servirte:

```
SELECT 
    a.articulo_id,
    (SELECT
        b.foto
     FROM photos b
     WHERE b.foto LIKE '%medium.jpg'
        AND b.service_id = a.service_id
        AND b.articulo_id = a.articulo.id) AS medium,
    (SELECT
        b.foto
     FROM photos b
     WHERE b.foto LIKE '%big.jpg'
        AND b.service_id = a.service_id
        AND b.articulo_id = a.articulo.id) AS big
FROM photos a
WHERE a.service_id = 1
```

Aunque yo lo que haría sería crear un campo en la tabla para cada tamaño, asi a la hora de consultar es mucho más sencillo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. He optado por crear una columna para cada tamaño :)

Comment: Me alegro de haber podido ayudar. Un saludo :)